# Ignore a property with PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to ignore a property with a property info such that;

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(GLAccount).GetProperty("ExampleProp");
modelBuilder.Entity<GLAccount>().Ignore(g => propertyInfo);
```

The above code block gives me the following error;

```
The expression 'g => value(Dashboard.DAL.Context+<>c__DisplayClass16_0).propertyInfo' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.'
```

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the property info instead of just doing `modelBuilder.Entity<GLAccount>().Ignore(glaAccount => glaAccount.ExampleProp);` or `modelBuilder.Entity<GLAccount>().Ignore("ExampleProp");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an API that expects an exppression-tree, you will need to build the lambda manually:

```cs
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(GLAccount));
var body = Expression.Property(p, propertyInfo);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<GLAccount, SomeType>>(body, p);
modelBuilder.Entity<GLAccount>().Ignore(lambda);
```

The problem here, though, is going to be knowing the `SomeType`. I'm assuming that `Ignore(...)` is actually `Ignore<TResult>(...)` or similar, in which the `TResult` would need to be the same as the `SomeType` above, which would need to be whatever the return type of `ExampleProp` is. You *may* need to use `MakeGenericMethod` here.

Also note that if you aren't doing *anything else* with `propertyInfo`, you can also use `Expression.Property(p, "ExampleProp")` as a short-cut.

Although... [from these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.ignore?view=efcore-3.0), you *might* be able to simply use:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<GLAccount>().Ignore("ExampleProp");
```